# How to run multiple "compass watch" through shell script in Cygwin?

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, compass-sass, compass

I want to run multiple "compass watch" commands through shell script in Cygwin. Looks like I've completely forgotten shell script. This is what I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
sitea="/cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/sitea/themes/siteatheme/css/"
siteb="/cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/siteb/themes/sitebtheme/css/"
sitec="/cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/sitec/themes/sitectheme/css/"
sited="/cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/sited/themes/sitedtheme/css/"
sitee="/cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/sitee/themes/siteetheme/css/"
sitef="/cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/sitef/themes/siteftheme/css/"

for i in sitea siteb sitec sited sitee sitef
  do
    compass watch "$i" &
  done
```

I am getting the following error message repeated 6 times:

```
$ C:\Installation\Ruby22-x64\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/Installation/Ruby22-x64/bin/compass (LoadError)
```

Looks like it's unable to find `compass` command but when I type in `compass watch` from the bash terminal, it runs ok. How do I fix this?

Comment: The error message is very clear. You have in the PATH a windows ruby installation that can not understand cygwin path

Comment: @matzeri So how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you installed cygwin ruby ? Have you `/usr/bin/` in the PATH before not cygwin directories ? It should be the default if you have not redefined PATH on `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

Fix this by passing Windows-style paths to compass, and by using cygstart.  try something like this:

`cygstart /cygdrive/c/Installation/Ruby22-x64/bin/compass watch $(cygpath -w $i)`

`cygstart` will pass control to windows shell.
`cygpath -w` will convert to Windows path.